# Get rid of prefactors, without altering the rest of expression

Tags: python, sympy

I have this expression in `sympy`

```
expr = 60378125*139**(13/16)*2143750**(1/8)*x**(9/4)*m**(1/4)/(15420489728*y**(1/4)*z**(3/4))
```

(Note: this actually comes from other calculations, which are too long to post here. So I am not sure I can work with anything different, e.g., an alternative expression using `Rational`).

I want to get rid of all numerical factors, keeping the rest of the expression, as in

```
expr2 = x**(9/4)*m**(1/4)/(y**(1/4)*z**(3/4))
```

How can I easily do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answers are also good but here are simpler ways:

```
In [5]: from sympy import symbols, Mul, Rational as R

In [6]: x, y, z, m = symbols('x y z m')

In [7]: expr = (60378125 * 139**R(13,16) * 2143750**R(1,8)
   ...:         * x**R(9,4) * m**R(1,4) / (15420489728 * y**R(1,4) * z**R(3,4)))

In [8]: expr
Out[8]: 
            13                       
            ──                       
            16 8 _________ 4 ___  9/4
60378125⋅139  ⋅╲╱ 2143750 ⋅╲╱ m ⋅x   
─────────────────────────────────────
                    4 ___  3/4       
        15420489728⋅╲╱ y ⋅z          

In [9]: Mul.make_args(expr)
Out[9]: 
⎛                13                                       ⎞
⎜                ──                                       ⎟
⎜  60378125      16  8 _________  4 ___   9/4    1     1  ⎟
⎜───────────, 139  , ╲╱ 2143750 , ╲╱ m , x   , ─────, ────⎟
⎜15420489728                                   4 ___   3/4⎟
⎝                                              ╲╱ y   z   ⎠

In [10]: [f for f in Mul.make_args(expr) if not f.is_number]
Out[10]: 
⎡4 ___   9/4    1     1  ⎤
⎢╲╱ m , x   , ─────, ────⎥
⎢             4 ___   3/4⎥
⎣             ╲╱ y   z   ⎦

In [11]: Mul(*[f for f in Mul.make_args(expr) if not f.is_number])
Out[11]: 
4 ___  9/4
╲╱ m ⋅x   
──────────
4 ___  3/4
╲╱ y ⋅z
```

This approach of using `make_args` to get the factors and filtering them could work for more general predicates so you could use this to select any subset of the factors of a `Mul` based on some arbitrary condition.

Actually what you are trying to do is quite a common operation and so there is a specific method for doing this:

```
In [19]: expr.as_independent(x, y, z, m, as_Add=False)
Out[19]: 
⎛            13                        ⎞
⎜            ──                        ⎟
⎜            16 8 _________  4 ___  9/4⎟
⎜60378125⋅139  ⋅╲╱ 2143750   ╲╱ m ⋅x   ⎟
⎜──────────────────────────, ──────────⎟
⎜       15420489728          4 ___  3/4⎟
⎝                            ╲╱ y ⋅z   ⎠

In [20]: expr.as_independent(x, y, z, m, as_Add=False)[1]
Out[20]: 
4 ___  9/4
╲╱ m ⋅x   
──────────
4 ___  3/4
╲╱ y ⋅z   

In [21]: expr.as_independent(*expr.free_symbols, as_Add=False)[1]
Out[21]: 
4 ___  9/4
╲╱ m ⋅x   
──────────
4 ___  3/4
╲╱ y ⋅z
```

Comment: Why `make_args` and not just `args`?

Comment: `make_args` will also handle the case that you do not actually have a `Mul` e.g. `(x**2).args` vs `Mul.make_args(x**2)`.

Comment: My `expr` is hardcoded here for the sake of the MCVE. 
But in use cases, it comes from other calculations, so I don't see how to apply the solution, since I don't have `Rational`s..

Comment: Use the last suggestion: `expr.as_independent(*expr.free_symbols, as_Add=False)[1]`. It works whether you are using Rationals or not.

Comment: None of what I showed above depends on there being Rationals apart from the line that constructs the expression. If the above does not work for other examples you are interested in then consider that when you hardcode an example you should clarify how other cases not shown might be similar/different from the example. Both suggestions above will `get rid of all numerical factors, keeping the rest of the expression` as asked for in the question.

Comment: 1. It might have been ambiguous whether changing the input (`expr`) was an option for me. Now it's explicitly clarified.
2. As mentioned by @smichr, `as_independent(...` works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could define the expression using `Rational()` to handle exponents as rational numbers, then create an list to store non-numeric factors. Next, iterate through the factors of the expression using and check if a factor is a power with the `isinstance()`. If it's a power, separate the base and exponent using `as_base_exp()`. Check if the base is a symbol and not a number and if the base is a symbol or the factor is a symbol, append it to the `non_numeric_factors`. After iterating through all the factors, multiply the `non_numeric_factors` together and the result is a new expression containing only the non-numeric factors:

```py
from sympy import symbols, Mul, Pow, Rational

x, y, z, m = symbols('x y z m')

expr = (60378125 * 139**(Rational(13, 16)) *
        2143750**(Rational(1, 8)) * x**(Rational(9, 4)) *
        m**(Rational(1, 4)) /
        (15420489728 * y**(Rational(1, 4)) * z**(Rational(3, 4))))

non_numeric_factors = []

for factor in Mul.make_args(expr):
    if isinstance(factor, Pow):
        base, exp = factor.as_base_exp()
        if base.is_symbol:
            non_numeric_factors.append(factor)
    elif factor.is_symbol:
        non_numeric_factors.append(factor)

expr2 = Mul(*non_numeric_factors)

print(expr2)
```

produces

```bash
m**(1/4)*x**(9/4)/(y**(1/4)*z**(3/4))
```

---

**EDIT:** to support any input string, just `parse_exp()` you received as your input instead of dealing with hardcoded one:

```py
from sympy import symbols, Mul, Pow, nsimplify, parse_expr

x, y, z, m = symbols('x y z m')

# Replace this with the input string you receive
input_str = '60378125*139**(13/16)*2143750**(1/8)*x**(9/4)*m**(1/4)/(15420489728*y**(1/4)*z**(3/4))'

# Parse the string into a Sympy expression
expr = parse_expr(input_str, evaluate=False)

# Simplify the expression, which will convert floating-point numbers to fractions
expr = nsimplify(expr)

non_numeric_factors = []

for factor in Mul.make_args(expr):
    if isinstance(factor, Pow):
        base, exp = factor.as_base_exp()
        if base.is_symbol:
            non_numeric_factors.append(factor)
    elif factor.is_symbol:
        non_numeric_factors.append(factor)

expr2 = Mul(*non_numeric_factors)

print(expr2)
```

Comment: My `expr` is hardcoded here for the sake of the MCVE. 
But in use cases, it comes from other calculations, so I don't see how to apply the solution.

Comment: Just parse your input string. See edited answer.

Comment: I don't have an input string. I guess I could stringify my expr though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pattern matching:

```py
from sympy import *
var("x, m, y, z")
expr1 = 60378125*139**(13/16)*2143750**(1/8)*x**(9/4)*m**(1/4)/(15420489728*y**(1/4)*z**(3/4))
# converts float numbers to rational numbers
expr1 = nsimplify(expr1)
# pattern matching:
# w1 selects every number
# w2 selects everything that is not a number
w1 = Wild("w1", properties=[lambda t: t.is_Number])
w2 = Wild("w2", exceptions=[lambda t: t.is_Number])
# find a product given by a number and something else
matches = expr1.match(w1 * w2)
# the final expression is just everything else without the factor (number)
expr = matches[w2]
print(expr)
# out: m**(1/4)*x**(9/4)/(y**(1/4)*z**(3/4))
```